# How to extract nc4 data from a shapefile in Java?

Tags: java, shapefile, netcdf-java

More specificly, I have a nc4 of rainfall from NASA and I have a shapefile with regions of Brazil.
I need to get the rainfall data for each region IN JAVA.

I was reading about https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-java library but could not find any sample of this scenario.